# add a sentiment column onto a dataset in r

Tags: r, data-analysis, data-science, sentiment-analysis

I have done some basic sentiment analysis in r and wanted to know if there was a way to have the sentiment of a sentence or row analyzed, and then have a column appended with the sentiment of the sentence. All analysis I have done up until now gives me an overview of the sentiment or pulls specific words, but doesn't link back to the original row of data

The input of my data would be fed in through a BI software and would look something like below with a case number and some text:

```
"12345","I am extremely angry with my service"
"23456","I was happy with how everything turned out"
"34567","The rep did a great job helping me"
```

I would like it to be returned as an output below

```
"12345","I am extremely angry with my service","Anger"
"23456","I was happy with how everything turned out","Positive"
"34567","The rep did a great job helping me","Positive"
```

Any point in the right direction of a package or resource would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you run into with sentences is that sentiment lexicons are based on words. If you look at the nrc lexicon, the word "angry" has three sentiment values: anger, disgust and negative. Which one do you choose? Or you have the sentence returning multiple words that are in a lexicon. Try testing different lexicons with your text to see what happens for example with `tidytext`.

If want a a package that can analyse sentiment on sentence level, you can look into `sentimentr`. You will not get sentiment values like anger back, but a sentiment/polarity score. More about `sentimentr` can be found in the [package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sentimentr/index.html) and on [sentimentr](https://github.com/trinker/sentimentr#sentimentr) github page.

A small example code:

```
library(sentimentr)
text <- data.frame(id = c("12345","23456","34567"),
                   sentence = c("I am extremely angry with my service", "I was happy with how everything turned out", "The rep did a great job helping me"),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)



sentiment(text$sentence)
   element_id sentence_id word_count  sentiment
1:          1           1          7 -0.5102520
2:          2           1          8  0.2651650
3:          3           1          8  0.3535534

# add sentiment score to data.frame
text$sentiment <- sentiment(text$sentence)$sentiment 

text
     id                                   sentence  sentiment
1 12345       I am extremely angry with my service -0.5102520
2 23456 I was happy with how everything turned out  0.2651650
3 34567         The rep did a great job helping me  0.3535534
```

Comment: thanks for the push in the right direction! I think this is what I was looking for.